# choose Gurobi as solver to deal with bilevel optimization in Pyomo

Tags: python, pyomo, gurobi

There is a bilevel optimization model. The upper level function is nonlinear and it has two sets of decision variables. I wanna formulate the model using Pyomo and solve it with Gurobi. Here is part of my code:
`your text`# define decision variables
model.H = pyo.Set(initialize = [h for h in range(experts)])
model.I = pyo.Set(initialize = [i for i in range(alternatives)])
model.o_a = pyo.Var(model.H, model.I, within= pyo.PercentFraction, bounds= (0,1))
model.o_r = pyo.Var(model.H, model.I, within=pyo.PercentFraction, bounds=(0, 1))
model.c = pyo.Var(model.H, within=pyo.NonNegativeReals, bounds=(0, 10))
# define 0-1 decision variables to decide wether need to adjust
model.x = pyo.Var(model.H, model.I, within=pyo.Binary)
# define the  parma
model.p = pyo.Param(default=0.08)
# define the adusted rule
`your text`def adjust_rule(model):
if orginal_d > model.p:
return model.x == 1
else:
return model.x == 0

```
# define the upper level objective function -max Ur-Uc-Utc
def Obj(model):
    for h in range(experts):
        for i in range(alternatives):
            value_1 = (model.o_a[h, i] - model.o_r[h, i]) ** 2
            value_2 = model.x[h, i] * value_1
            value_3 = model.c[h] * model.x[h, i]
            value_4 = (model.o_a[h, i] - ind_o[h, i]) ** 2
            value_5 = value_3 * value_4
            value_6 = model.x[h, i] * t[h]
    return value_2-value_5-value_6
model.uobj = pyo.Objective(rule=Obj(model), sense=pyo.maximize)
```

When I run the code,I get the error message:
`your text`pyomo.solvers.plugins.solvers.gurobi_direct.DegreeError: GurobiDirect does not support expressions of degree None.
Could you please tell how to solve this error?